# Search by autoincrement number PHP/ MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a dual search functionality using PHP/HTML and MySql.

I have one search method working where the user is able to search keywords of an item to return records that contain part of the inputted text.

But I also want a search function to search by product ID (1-25) and then to explicitly return that result.

This is the code I have already:

```
$find_title = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM `catalog` WHERE `keywords` LIKE'%$search%'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($find_title))
{
    $title =$row['title'];

    echo $title."<br />";

}
```

This is working, but how do I create another search box to return results when an just ID integer alone is searched?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just add another query that searches for that specific ID:

```
SELECT *
FROM catalog
WHERE idColumn = `inputID`
```